# how to accessing @autowired variable in mvn install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, integration-testing, spring-kafka

i have these 2 classes for integration testing using JUnit

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class KafkaTestHelper {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{kafkaTestHelper.getTopics()}")
    public void onListen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        log.info("#OnListen topic : {}, record : {}", record.topic(), record);
        this.messages.put(record.topic(), record);
        log.info("put on object {}", System.identityHashCode(messages));
        printHashMap();
    }

     public String getMessageByTopic(String topic) {
        log.info("#trying to consume from {}", topic);
        log.info("consuming from object {}", System.identityHashCode(messages));
        printHashMap();
        String message = getMessage(topic);
        log.info("#returning message : {}", message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

and then test class that `@Autowired` class above

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ImsStockApplication.class,},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTestHelper kafkaTestHelper;

    @Test
    public void success() throws Exception {

        producer.send("someTopics").block();

        String valueFail = kafkaTestHelper.getMessageByTopic("someTopic"); // always empty on mvn build
        Assert.assertNotNull(valueFail);
    }
}
```

So the idea was simple, my test class publishing topic, and then the topic consumed then publishing another topic as a result.
The result listened in the helper and i want to assert it in my test class.
If i build and run, this code was able to run perfectly fine, but, the problem is, when I did `mvn install` it is not.
Then i tried to log the listening and consuming activity in my helper and found this behavior that I didnt understand

If i build and run this normally it will listening, storing, and consuming records from the same object `messages`

```
Receive from topic someTopics with message somerecords
#OnListen topic : someTopics, record : somerecords
put on object 1654595627          <- same object id

#trying to consume someTopics
consuming from object 1654595627  <- same object id
```

but when i did `mvn install`, it shows differently

```
Receive from topic someTopics with message somerecords
#OnListen topic someTopics, record : somerecords
put on object 1869941502            <- different object id

#trying to consume from someTopics
consuming from object 1398482101    <- different object id
```

the incoming records always stored in object `1869941502` and consume from object `1398482101`

shouldn't it be the same like the example above? since it should be accessing the same object right? why it only happens on `mvn install` and not normal build from the IDE.

Any idea/solution guys? Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your test logic is not valid.

The producer and consumer are processed on different threads. Even if you publish with that `block()` on the main JUnit thread, the consumption happens in fully different thread. And you cannot assert consumption result just immediately after publishing. You need to wait for some barrier to be sure that consumer receives the data.

I understand that it is not desirable to modify a production code of the listener for some testing purpose, so I'd suggest you take a look into a [Awaitility utils](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) to ask for data to assert during some period until it fails or fulfilled.

Probably until that `valueFail != null`.

Comment: i did tried using awaitility before, but still same result. but if it has something to do with the test logic, why is it only happened when i tried `mvn install` ? and how about the object id, is that means something?

Comment: Probably you have some other tests which interact with the same topic. So, same listener picks us that data as well....

Comment: i dont think so, because the test will run sequencially right? and also in my helper, i have logic to remove consumed topic, so it will not causing issue in other tests. 
And again, it was fine without `mvn install`, that is the big why i was wondering

Comment: Any chances that you can share the project with us to reproduce and play with?

Comment: well don't think so, it is a company's project that depends on many others company's services. Even if i could, i cant share it here. is there any other way?

Comment: You probably just can create a simple independent Spring Boot project which can expose the problem. What you show is very likely some race condition. You probably can dump the content of that `messages` map in your `getMessageByTopic()` to see what records are received so far.

Comment: i'll see what i can do and will get back here again after